# Modify U-Boot to rely on addresses in mmc instead of filesystem

Tags: u-boot, fault-tolerance

For context, I'm trying to make everything in flash as fault-tolerant as possible. Ideally, I'd like to just store the kernel image and initrd file as just BLOBs on MMC.

So as I understand, U-Boot looks for an extlinux.conf or boot.scr file, but as I said I'd rather not rely on the filesystem tables at all.

Would it be safe to just do everything in the `main_loop` function by just calling `mmc read...` to load in the kernel image, followed by the boot command? Do I need to do something with the `initrd` file too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, you would partition your MMC device such that you use `mmc read ...` to bring in the kernel, device tree, and if used by your system, initrd in to DDR and then use `bootm` to start the system.  You'll also want to have the partition table on your device mark the area where you have the kernel, etc, as reserved in some manner.